# Parse email attachments for specific strings on _ItemSend Event

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012, outlook, outlook-addin

Pretty large order here, but alot of my research has led me down wrong roads. Basic idea is a user inserts an attachment and OnClick for the ItemSend event it parses that attachment for specific strings then Cancel=True on the ItemSend event where I would then make them choose a route. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to search the string in the name of the attachment?

Comment: That might be my alternative to the later which is to actually search through a document or excel spreadsheet eihrr when the user attached the item or tried to send it

Comment: Sorry, but thats beyond my knowledge...

Comment: Ideas on how to detect a string in the filename for specific strings? This is not working

Comment: If (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(attachment.FileName) = "specific string.*")

Answer (score 0):

```
If (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(attachment.FileName) = "specific string.*")
```

–  user3078575

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment.

Comment: The OP answered his own question in a comment which is more hidden than an answer, Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.